# is php artisan make::controller required for Laravel development?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm starting out learning Laravel, and all the tutorials show how to use

```
php artisan make:controller BlahController
```

to make a new controller.

Is there a requirement I do this from the command line?  If I want to do it by hand, what would I need to do to replicate that action?

I know that of course, I'd need to manually create the BlahController.php file inside the app\http\Controllers folder.

But does artisan make:controller alter/create any other files?

Broader question.  Is php artisan required at all to work in Laravel?  Or can all development be done by hand coding?

Comment: It is not required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not required at all to use php artisan to create any files.

The purpose of artisan is to make your work more automated or less coding in general, but you are 100% correct, you can just manually create the controller file on its own (or model or view or anything related to laravel) without using artisan.

**Example of artisan is to do things like:**

```
php artisan create:model MyModel -all
```

**This will create:**

1. migration
2. seeder
3. factory
4. policy
5. resource controller
6. form request classes for the model

*all of that is created and ready to be edited in a single command* rather than having to manually create each file and filling it up and checking if the names are correct etc...

You can do so many things with artisan to simplify the process, and you can always read more on what options you have when creating things by doing:

```
php artisan create:controller -help
```

[image]

More of the documentation can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#introduction

Comment: Thanks for the help.  About my other question.  When I use artisan to create things (like controllers), does it just create that controller.php file?  Or does it also keep some sort of manifest file that keeps track of all the stuff it's creating?  I guess the reason why I want to know is, if I make a mistake, then, if all it does is create the file and nothing else, then I can just delete the changes.  On the other hand, if it's also doing some sort of recordkeeping, then I'd also need to understand how to modify that too, in order to undo changes manually.  Still very new, I came from Zend.

Comment: If you type `php artisan make:controller YourController` it will only create that controller and nothing else, which you can create manually by yourself, there are no manifests or tracking, its just a helper to assist you, for most developers using shared hosting without access to the terminal, they never use it anyways :D and go on to create large projects.

Comment: Thanks.  That solves my main concern.  I forgot what framework it was, but a long time ago, I had a similar situation, where the command line tool would keep record keeping, so undoing anything was difficult, since I couldn't find any documentation on how to edit the recordkeeping file.  I'm glad Laravel isn't this way.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel artisan helps you to do things faster
Ofcourse you can create it manually but artisan makes your life a little bit easier!
I highly recommend it
Also It's not about just creating a controller
It does a lot, read more about it here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may want to consider adding some brief bullets about what else Artisan can do.